# Sony VAIO unknown device

Tags: sony-vaio, chipset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where should I find drivers for my laptop if it didn't come with a driver disk?](https://superuser.com/questions/230139/where-should-i-find-drivers-for-my-laptop-if-it-didnt-come-with-a-driver-disk)

My VAIO is VPCCW2HGX/B. I have installed Windows 7 64 bit. I have downloaded and installed all drivers from Sony's website. But there is an unknown device on device manager. Device's location is on "Intel(R) PM55 Express Chipset LPC Interface Controller - 3B03". I installed motherboard drivers.

Comment: See [How to find drivers for my laptop if it didn't come with a driver disk](http://superuser.com/questions/230139/) for more on finding unknown drivers.

Answer (score 3):

You can probably find out what it is with the device IDs. In Device Manager, open the preferences of you Unknown Device and go to the "Details" tab. In the dropdown menu, choose "Device Instance ID". This will show at least one string like this:

HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_**11D4**&DEV_**1984**&SUBSYS_10280211&REV_1004

It might not be complete (because the device is unknown, the Device Class (like "HDAUDIO" in my example), but you'll at least have the string after VEN_ and the one after DEV_. Write those down. The first is the Vendor ID and the second is Device ID (it's not vendor-specific to my knowledge, so you can use it on its own).

Now go to a site like [PCI Database](http://www.pcidatabase.com/) and search for the Device ID in the appropriate field. That sould return the device name. If there's more on the list, do a second search with the vendor ID. With that, you should be able to look for the proper drivers.

Comment: I found it so useful information.