# asus eee top: Where drivers for windows 7 can be found

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I see that ASUS support site is very hard to navigate... I wonder where I can find drivers for my device. Did anybody come across similar issue?

Comment: Check out our [Community FAQ](http://superuser.com/tags/community-faq/info) post on **[where to find drivers if you don't have the driver disk](http://superuser.com/q/230139/20088)**. It was written with laptops in mind, but should apply to your Eee top as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's also a driver info page on the Windows site that may also be helpful: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Update-a-driver-for-hardware-that-isnt-working-properly