# Old driver version: ATI Radeon HD 3450 version 8.513.1.0

Tags: drivers, amd-radeon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where should I find drivers for my laptop if it didn't come with a driver disk?](https://superuser.com/questions/230139/where-should-i-find-drivers-for-my-laptop-if-it-didnt-come-with-a-driver-disk)

This driver software is from 2008.  I'm waiting on a response from the Dell support community, but thought you might know of a driver repository I can search.

Comment: are you looking for a new driver, or you want this specific old driver?

Comment: Yeah, you don't actually say what you want.  Do you need this driver?  Do you want a newer one?  (Why do you want a newer one if the old one works fine?)

Comment: Sorry, I want the old driver version, not the new one, as the new one causes 2 WinXP desktops to regularly freeze.  I think information has been removed from my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the CD-ROM which came with the hardware did contain a stable driver, but I could see no driver on it when I browsed it.

Both desktops are working with the reinstalled driver.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a guess here, and assume you're looking for an updated video driver for Windows? ATI/AMD video drivers can be downloaded from http://game.amd.com.

However, you should be warned that the most recent drivers usually do not perform significantly better and sometimes work worse than older versions, especially for the less recent cards.

In particular, some AGP cards need patched drivers to work with later Catalyst releases.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has already been answered, but to anyone else browsing this question and looking for an alternative - you might have luck looking on **oldapps.com**.

For example, the 8.5 version of the ATI drivers can be downloaded from here:
http://www.oldapps.com/ati.php?old_ati_drivers=9