# How can I identify my network card in my laptop?

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers, compaq-laptop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where should I find drivers for my laptop if it didn’t come with a driver disk?](https://superuser.com/questions/230139/where-should-i-find-drivers-for-my-laptop-if-it-didnt-come-with-a-driver-disk)

I have a Compaq Presario CQ57, and I had to reformat it yesterday. The OS works great, except now I can not get my wireless and ethernet to work. Under'Network Devices,' it only says 'Ethernet Controller' and 'PCI Device.' How can I identify what the card actually is so that I can download the drivers on another computer?

Comment: Have you tried going to the [official site](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/ProductList.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&taskId=135&prodTypeId=321957&prodSeriesId=5091489) and selecting the drivers for your laptop? You seem to know that you can throw them on USB/CD from another computer to install them. Or are we talking about an aftermarket addition to the machine? Or are you saying that on the official page there are several drivers and you don't know which one to use? Ethernet should be part of the mobo or just a realtek LAN driver Once you have that windows update should work for wlan

Comment: There are several drivers, and I am not sure how to pick one.. I tried to find more information about the card on the computer, but it's not there or I don't know how to find it (probably the latter).

Comment: Get the realtek LAN driver for ethernet and see if windows update will ID the WLAN and driver for it. I'm assuming you don't have recovery discs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The laptop could come with one of several WLAN cards. If you download all available from the site mentioned by @climenole, you can simply try each one. It should only take a small amount of time.

Also, the card may be acessible from the cover on the bottom and can be quickly identified - here's the  [Manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02786367.pdf) that may help.

You may know what you had before the reinstall and can eliminate one of the following:

- Atheros AR9002WB-1NGB 802.11b/g/n 1x1 WiFi and Bluetooth 2.1+EDR Combo Adapter (BT3.0+HS ready)
- Ralink 5390GN 802.11b/g/n 1x1 WiFi Adapter
- Realtek 8188BC8 802.11a/b/g/n 2x2 WiFi and Bluetooth 3.0+HS Combo Adapter
- Realtek 8188GN 802.11b/g/n 1x1 WiFi Adapter

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to identify which version of the Compaq Presario CQ57 model you have and download drivers for this specific model/version [directly from HP](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/ProductList.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&taskId=135&prodTypeId=321957&prodSeriesId=5091489) or ask to [the HP forum](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/).

Hope this helps. Let us know.

Answer (score 0):

[Go to the HP partsurfer site](http://partsurfer.hp.com/) and punch in your HP product number in the quick search box (not model number), it will list what wireless adapter that was sold with that particular product build. Then download the correct driver from the HP drivers page for your model as suggested by others.

[How to find your product number](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/findModel?cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en)