# My keyboard's PRINT-SCREEN (prntscr) won't work

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, printing, dell-inspiron

I'm using a Dell Inspiron n5010 laptop with Windows 7 64.

The <kbd>PrntScr</kbd> key won't capturing anything to clipboard.

I **don't** want to use OSK (on-screen keyboard), or snipping tool or external keyboard, though PrntScr works with OSK.

<kbd>PrntScr</kbd> is the only key not working.. But no problem with entire keyboard hardware.

Does anyone know how to simulate the same print screen operation with other keyboard keys? Or any utility available in any websites?

Comment: Are the hotkey drivers installed?

Comment: No.. is hotkey drivers must be installed to get the prntscr work?? where can I find hotkey drivers..?

Comment: No idea but it's worth a try. You get them from the manufacturer's website.

Comment: read here for more info http://superuser.com/questions/230139/where-should-i-find-drivers-for-my-laptop-if-it-didnt-come-with-a-driver-disk

Answer (score 1):

If your laptop is still under warranty contact Dell support. They will replace your keyboard for free.

Comment: You're welcome PM me if u DELL product problems