# UI freezing in certain applications in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, freeze, vlc-media-player, qbittorrent

I apologize in advance for the length of this post. I'm just trying to describe my problems as accurately as possible.

Some months ago I bought a new laptop, and a pretty powerful one at that. It's an MSI gaming laptop, the full model name is MSI GT72S 6QE-208CZ Dominator Pre G. It came with Windows 10 (I've been using Windows 7 up to that point).
It's a high performance machine, but I've noticed there was this glitch right from the start: some applications seemed to have problems with their UI freezing up. 
Here's what's happening:

One of the apps I'm having problems with is the VLC media player. When I use it to watch a movie, I usually lose the ability to fully control the player seconds after I start the movie. The navigation slider on the bottom stops working, if I'm in full screen it won't even appear when I move the mouse. Context menus and main application menus work at first, but they quickly get sluggish, then only appear as outlines (only the border of the menu appears) then they stop showing up altogether. The video keeps playing, and I can play/pause with the keyboard. Things like adjusting player volume via keyboard still work. But that's about it. Another thing that happens is the VLC application won't terminate when I try to close it. The 'x' button doesn't work, (and in full screen it's not even there, and I can't exit full screen) so I right-click on the VLC icon in task bar and select close. This makes the VLC window disappear. However, There is still a VLC icon in the sys-tray, (right-clicking on it only brings up a transparent outline of a context menu.) There is also a VLC process visible in the task manager, and killing the process through the task manager is the only way to truly end it. This is especially annoying, because it forces me to use the built in Windows Media Player instead. (this is obviously something I don't want to do, nobody should be using that thing. Not to mention it doesn't seem to support embedded subtitles, dual languages etc.)

Another app I'm having problems with is qBittorrent. It's a lightweight bittorrent client. The symptoms are very similar. Let's say I click on a torrent link in my browser, this in turn starts up qBittorrent. The main application window shows up, and so does a dialog window that asks me to select download location. I make a selection and click OK, everything works fine. But then I click on another torrent link. The dialog comes up again, but this time it freezes. When I try to click on the main window, I get a cue telling me a modal dialog is open. But the dialog is completely non-responsive. Context menus and regular menu bar menus also like to freeze up the UI. The only option I have at this point is to kill the application via task manager and start it again.

At first I didn't think much of the glitches. At the time Windows 10 was still relatively new. So I blamed the problems on those apps not being compatible with Windows 10. I learned to work around the glitches, and kept expecting either a Windows update or an update for those applications to fix it.

When that didn't happen, I started googling around, and found nothing. I asked on the MSI forums, all I got back was "It sounds like application bugs of VLC & qBittorrent with Windows 10."... yeah... it doesn't.

I stopped trying to solve this issue again, partly because I was lazy, and partly out of frustration at not being able to solve it.

Today I installed an application I used to use on my old laptop. It's called Calibre, it's an ebook management software. I started the app, brought up a context menu, and it froze. I nearly started tearing my hair out. Guys, I need to fix this.

The sad part is, I'm a programmer. I've been installing my own operating systems since I was about 10. And I have no idea what to do. I know this is not caused by insufficient performance of the machine. This thing can run Doom on full details, there's no way it can't play a movie that my old laptop from 6 years ago could play. Or run a fairly low-demand desktop application. 
When I installed CS:GO, it asked me to turn off something called "Game DVR", which I did. I thought that might help. It didn't. My guess is it might be some such garbage feature interfering with the applications, but I have no idea what to look for. 
Please, help.

Comment: You can write a comment for your own question if you want. But replacing it whole with a comment only confuses the hell out of its readers and wastes a good question too. Please be advised that mods can lock a question if such a things happened.

Comment: As for the use of the words "app" and "application": You had used both in your original post and making the usage consistent is a sound editorial decision. However, your post was also very long and I though we could shorten it without sacrificing meaning. "App" was shorter. Here is the memo you say you didn't receive: http://www.americandialect.org/app-voted-2010-word-of-the-year-by-the-american-dialect-society-updated

Comment: *major* edits arn't generally a good idea, especially when its against the intent of the user. Also, applications is much better than software. Rolled it back to the last substantial edit that seemed true to the original question - @shaggydog *might* want to consider shortening the questions as per the most recent edit, but that's their decision, not yours.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Need must! The length was scaring away potential respondents and I fixed it. And I will do so again in the future. Feel free to show me a written rule against it.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Actually, you can't! Because our written rule says "try to make the post significantly better when you edit". So, it turns out *major* edits are actually the correct thing do.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried disabling Nahimic? I'm having similar issues (with Telegram, Tortoise HG, Origin, ...) which all seems to be using QT, and found this:

[Applications freezing the computer on performing simple actions on Windows 10.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/applications-freezing-the-computer-on-performing/9ede927d-a69b-4d70-9ee9-6f461a5579f6)

> I tried disabling all the startup entries, and now the programs all
>   work fine. On enabling what i needed one by one, it seems that there
>   was a program, Nahimic, that was causing this. So i reinstalled my
>   Audio drivers, and nahimic and now my tex editors all seem to  work
>   fine.

Looks like updating Nahimic to 2.3.1 corrected the issue for me. I haven't had any random freezings lately. However I also did a full reinstall for the computer (because of other issues), but previously that alone haven't helped.

Comment: Interesting find. My investigation shows that this certain model of laptop indeed has Nahimic Audio Enhancer.

Answer (score 0):

> all I got back was "It sounds like application bugs of VLC & qBittorrent with
> Windows 10."... yeah... it doesn't.

I completely agree with you.
Having recently experienced freezing and/or sluggish behavior myself (and solved
them - I hope), my best bet is that your problems have nothing at all
to do with the particular applications you refer to (VLC, qBittorrent, Calibre).

Instead I rather strongly suggest it has to do with bad drivers. And when it
comes to *freezing* in particular, I am inclined to say ***graphics drivers***.
This I base *both* on my own experience *and* on what I have read online.

See for example the first reference below, but note that ***I don't suggest***
"switching to integrated Intel HD graphics" (drivers).
The problem is: drivers have a tendency to become a true nightmare, so you need
to be very careful!

You already mention Windows Update. To have Windows Update install the drivers
for you is probably the easiest and most secure way to do it.
You may need to trigger Windows Update to make it do anything.
What I have in mind is to disable the driver in Device Manager and then call
for Windows Update.

*How do you trigger Windows Update to update the driver(s) for you?*
Here is what I would try. Hit the <kbd>WinKey</kbd> and paste (or type)
`devmgmt` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image: Device Manager - Disable device]

After disabling the device, hit <kbd>WinKey</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>, then
`Update & Security` > `check for updates`. When you think Windows Update has
download and installed the driver, enter again Device Manager and see if
anything has happened. Restarting your computer might as usual be a good idea.

---

In case you download the drivers yourself, you badly need to make sure that you
get it from a reputable site and/or that you test the installer at https://www.virustotal.com/gui/.
Else you are greatly at risk of downloading and installing malware, going from
bad to **much** worse.

The best way to download drivers is undoubtedly to get the official drivers
directly from the vendor - in your case from nVidia - or better still: from
MSI.
You need to get the ***exactly*** right driver, the one that is made for your
graphics card.
Once you have the right driver, you can also try to get the latest version.
Not easy but doable - depending on how stubborn you are and how much time you
are wiling to spend ...

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42888024#43762587
https://www.virustotal.com/gui/
https://superuser.com/questions/230139#264743

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect to get an answer on this after close to 4 years. I strongly suspect the first answer was correct, it was probably the Nahimic audio driver suite. However, before that answer came I got tired of looking for the culprit and reinstalled Windows. So I'll never know if the answer was correct.